# Moving UITableView in xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a simple question for you.
I load images and strings from sqlite3 base. If there is no image, i want to move up my table view.
How can I realize it?  I tried to change frame.origin.x, but it doesn't work.
Link to my project https://github.com/serg1991/diplom

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the exact position of your problem in your project? It's kinda big.

Also, if you need to move up your view, what you want to modify is `frame.origin.y`.

Otherwise, make sure you don't change your tableView's frame too early in the view lifecycle. Try doing that in the -viewDidLoad of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to use a TableViewController in storyboard... Use a viewController, and drag a tableview inside (of course now you'll have to manage the delegates your self).

Hop this can help

Comment: Yes, i used viewController instead TableViewController. Could you please take a look of my project at github?

Comment: I presume your controller is APPChildViewController. Can you check if you go true "- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)ob..." ? Sorry but I could not download all Git project to debug ;-D PS, the name in the headers are not always the same... may be you should put your name + ref to the source of inspiration...

Comment: so, you said me to create new viewController at storyboard instead using xib? sorry, my English is not so good

Comment: No, don't change your storyboard as this is how we build the app since iOS 5 or 6... But please check my previous massage (debug to see if you go true the procedure). PS : don't worry about english, this is also not my natural language...